# A decision tree algorithm with a way to club the many levels of a categorical variable into 2 groups

Tags: r, decision-tree, rpart

I have a file which has data on customers defaulting on loans or not. There are many variables in this file. One such variable is "customer.employername". This variable has around 1000+ unique values of employer names of the customers. I want to use this variable in a logistic regression model where i want to predict who will be a defaulter or non defaulter but since this variable has so many categorical values, it is difficult to create dummy variable for each of these levels. Now for that, I want to come up with a decision tree algorithm in R where I can club all the levels of this "customer.employername" variable into two groups- Group 1 (consisting of all employer names for those customers who have defaulted) and Group 2 (consisting of all the employer names for those customers who have not defaulted). Can anyone please suggest me the coding for this desired algorithm? Thanking in anticipation

Answer (score 0):

You might consider `RandomForest`. Effectively, a random forest **is** based on decision trees, but rather than having 1 decision tree, you grow a forest of decision trees to get to a given target value, but you do so with replacement. So rather than make 1 tree, you make hundreds by bootstrapping your dataset with replacement. In my experience, `RandomForest` plays very nicely with a categorical or continuous variables, or a mix of the two. In general, I typically get very reproducible results as well. Also, the method is well supported in R with many libraries available.

Comment: I would look into it. I am trying to solve this problem using rpart function but since I am little new to R, getting the results is bit time consuming.

Comment: In a sense, there isn't much difference between `Rpart` and `RandomForest`, as they are both building trees to predict. The biggest advantage to RF is that you are building MANY trees, with replacement. One reason I really like RF is that if you have a few auto-correlated variables that also happen to be strong predictors, RF isn't likely to overfit. Running only one forest puts you in serious jeopardy of randomly getting a good or bad fit depending on whatever tree structure you ended up with. Think of RF like Rpart, but bootstrapped many times.